# Is there an OSS Solution, regarding Application Release Automation?

Tags: open-source, software-development, automation

Is there an OSS Solution, regarding Application Release Automation?

Based on this list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_release_automation

I see only paid version of this kind of software on this list. But is there any OSS, solution that accomplishes the "wiki requirements of ARA"?

Thank you.

Comment: That report is from 2014 so it is not applicable today. Jenkins can do all the requirements of ARA today

Comment: Hmm. I think Jenkins does the first half of "ARA" well and so far the second half "crude". At least when it comes to comparing the second half to products on that list that have been in dev at least since then. Such as XLRlease.

Comment: Specifically I am referring to Jenkins doing the: release coordination.
Also from XLRelease.
"get visibility into your release pipelines -- at enterprise scale"

Aside from the Products.
   I am most stuck on the definition of ARA software. As it sounds
like it is referring to software that is a wrapper around Jenkins.
Using Jenkins "at its core", and managing across all envs.
What then is ARA?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but you've already [asked this question before](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/39010/185) and it got closed for a reason. While this one is slightly better, it's still in the same category: what are your requirements? Please list them explicitly (no, it's not enough to "link" them – at least your basic requirements must be named explicitly, especially as that page does not list any requirements), or we'd again have to put this on hold for being too broad ([list-type questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), you remember).